# N-MOSFET switching an H-bridge: problems with PWM

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, h-bridge, nmos

In this circuit an Arduino digital pin drives the Gate of a N-MOSFET. When the pin is HIGH, current can flow from the H-Bridge GND to board GND. When it's LOW, current can't flow. What I need is to switch the H-Bridge ON/OFF in order to stop its quiescent power.

Everything works fine except when I use PWM signals in the H-Bridge INPUT pins. In this case, when the MCU suddenly sets the Gate pin LOW, the motors still move a little bit or they make a noise just like they are receiving power but not enough to move.

The MCU is working at 16 MHz speed, and the PWM instruction used is analog.Write(pin, 180); (range values 0-255)
(*I name the instruction only to help calculate the switching frequency)

I'm quite sure I should have put a pull-down resistor in parallel from the Arduino digital pin to GND. In other words, pulling down the Gate to 0V. I tried to stick manually a through-hole resistor but it didn't solve the problem.

The N-MOSFET is: AOD2922

[image]

Comment: I suggest you try to make your schematic more complete. Show what's driving the IN pins of the L2930. Show how your N_MOSFET is connected to the rest of the circuit, as it doesn't seem to be doing anything there by itself.

Comment: You want to float the MOSFET driver ground to reduce its quiescent power? This sounds like a really bad idea to me. Why not just control the enable pins with the MOSFET, shutting the drivers down?

Comment: You mean an actual physical mass, moving under an amount of fixed kinetic energy, doesn't just stop moving over an infinitesimally small distance? That sounds pretty much like what we agreed to the Universe being like up to this point. Try what happens when you go 120km/h and let go of the gas. You'd be pretty confused if your car immediately stopped, I imagine. And also what @AdamLawrence says.

Comment: @brhans I'm drawing a more complete schematic. Thank you.

Comment: @AdamLawrence The MCU, in a specific part of the program, needs to be sleeping. Theoretically, the ATMEGA328P sleep function disables all the digital pins. So, when it goes to sleep even the L293D enable pins are disabled. In practice, I wasn't sure that the quiescent power was disabled too. I preferred to think to an ideal switch to be sure. Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: @Asmyldof I'm not speaking about infinitesimal distance. The motors are embedded in a gearbox so the friction of the gears couldn't admit an inertia of 1-2 seconds. I know my model, it should stop almost immediately. Furthermore, the kinetic energy is balanced around the motor axis and it doesn't weight like a flywheel.

Comment: Switching the L293D positive supply with a P-MOSFET will probably give you better results. Remember to put a *pull-up* resistor on the P-MOSFET gate to keep it off when the MCU goes to sleep.

Comment: @brhans Do you think that a P-MOSFET may manage an high frequency PWM?

Comment: P-MOSFETs can be PWMed just like N-MOSFETs, but I thought your PWM signals were going to the L293D IN pins and that the MOSFET was just to turn the whole driver on/off.

Comment: @brhans Yes, it is so. The only PWM signals goes from ATMEGA328 digital pins to L293D IN pins. They are only signals. The power comes from a regulated 5V big trace that connects to L293D pins 10 and 20.

Comment: @brhans Ok to put a pull-up resistor to the PMOSFET gate to keep it off as default state. Understood. It may seems a stupid question but with the pull-up resistor I can't understand now when the gate turns to 0V in order to switch ON the MOSFET. MCU's digital pin outputs 0V or +5V. What happens to the gate when it receives 0V or +5V?

Comment: What the MOSFET 'cares' about is the voltage *difference* between gate & source. If source is 5V and gate is 5V then then the difference is 0, so the MOSFET is off.

Comment: @brhans Ok that was clear. So when the MCU,s pin outputs 0V, the gate is 0V and the difference Vgs will be -5V. Is that correct?

Comment: @brhans Could you please help me with this doubt?

Comment: Yes, Vgs will be -5V in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I interpret your question correctly, this is probably what is happening:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWpOo3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Most ICs have ESD protection circuit at the I/O pins which is represented by D1 and D2 above. When you want to disable the L293D by floating the "GND", "GND" gets pull toward Vcc by the loads. Current may flow through D2 as represented by the arrows.

Therefore, your MCU output is trying to power the circuit by pulling "GND" down through D2.

You are lucky that the H-bridge is powered by +5V. If it were +12V or something, it would probably burn out the MCU output.

Floating the "GND" of a circuit tends to have undesirable side effects. I avoid it because of the effort needed to take care of all the side effects and the risk of missing some.

Another side effect here is when the MOSFET is on, it still has significant resistance. That mean "GND" is not at 0V and would fluctuate depending on the load. So everything that are reference to "GND" are offset, that includes all the input pins.

Comment: Thank you so much. So, what is the most efficient way to stop quiescent power of L293D?

Comment: If the H-bridge is indeed powered by +5V, then a 5V MCU can drive a high side PMOS. Have to account for the potential reactive voltage from the inductive load during turn off, perhaps by sequencing (disable L293D first sometime before cutting power), rely on a bypass cap to L293D and/or additional voltage clamping. You still need to take care of the inputs, such as, the MCU cannot try to drive the inputs high when power is cut.